# Format date output in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date

I'm new to PHP and do not consider myself a coder. I am tackling my first database driven action and am having trouble getting the date output to format properly. The line where I am formatting the date seems to be ignored.  Am I doing something incredibly wrong?

This is what outputs on the page:

```
Comment from: Jeremiah
1289594028

here is my comment
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];


    if($name && $comment and ereg("^[A-Za-z0-9' -]+$",$name) and ereg("^[A-Za-z0-9' -,.:;()!?&#@'/]+$",$comment))

    {
        mysql_query("insert into pilot_comments (name,comment,date,page) values ('$name', '$comment',NOW(),'challenge1')");
    }

    elseif($_POST['submitted']==1) 

    { 
        echo "<img src='images/structure/commenting_spacer.png' height='1' width='249'>";

        echo "<br /><br /><div style='width:209px; background-color:#ff0000; padding:20px'><span class='white bold fourteen'>Uh oh! You may have:<br /><br />(1) Entered special characters, or <br /><br />(2) Not entered text into both fields.</span><br /><br /><span class='white twelve'>(This helps me fight spam. Thanks for understanding.)</span></div><br /><br />";
    }

?>

<?php

    $result = mysql_query("select name,comment,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) from pilot_comments where page='challenge1' order by date desc");

    echo mysql_error();

    $date = date("l, F j, Y \a\t g:i:s \P\S\T",$date);

    while(list($name,$comment,$date) = mysql_fetch_row($result))

    {
        echo "<img src='images/structure/commenting_spacer.png' height='1' width='249'>";

        echo "<div STYLE='word-wrap:break-word;width:249px;left:0px'><span class='twelve gray'><br />Comment from: </span><span class='twelve gray bold'>$name</span></div>";

        echo "<span class='ten light-gray bold'>$date<br /><br /></span>";

        echo "<div STYLE='word-wrap:break-word;width:249px;left:0px'><span class='fourteen green bold'>$comment</span></div><br /><br />";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move this line:

```
$date = date("l, F j, Y \a\t g:i:s \P\S\T",$date);
```

inside the while loop (where a new `$date` is created in every iteration, so your formatting goes lost):

```
 while(list($name,$comment,$date) = mysql_fetch_row($result))

    {

     $date = date("l, F j, Y \a\t g:i:s \P\S\T",$date);

     ... rest goes here ...
```

By the way, your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection-closed). You should fix that before using the script in real world use by wrapping every mention of `$_POST` in an escape function like so:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
```

Comment: And of course, MySQL is perfectly capable of doing the date formatting itself: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format. Might be better to do it DB-side, and save a double-conversion (mysql date -> string instead of mysql -> php -> string).

Comment: Thank you. Works with no issues. And extra thanks for tightening up my security!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not display errors, because with your code, you should at least get a warning for $date, which is undefined when used the first time.

This is like driving without any dashboard.

If you are working on a development environment, make sure errors are displayed (display_errors apache setting), and that your error level is high (set the error_reporting setting to -1 for maximum error output).

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `$date = date("l, F j, Y \a\t g:i:s \P\S\T",$date);` into the `while` loop

With it outside of the loop, the value from the database is not getting stored in `$date` for each iteration of the loop.

You also need to change `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)` to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as date` in the query so that the variable gets saved in the result row with the name your code is expecting.